# What is a block in Swift 4 and how do I fill in the parameter of the scheduledTimer method?

Tags: swift

```
class func scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval interval: TimeInterval, 
                  repeats: Bool, 
                    block: @escaping (Timer) -> Void) -> Timer
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_closures.htm

Comment: See [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+is%3Aa+Timer.scheduledTimer+-selector) for many examples.

Comment: I don't know what you are working on, but I would stop and take at least a couple of hours to really look at and study closures.  While in the past most of Cocoa was delegate pattern, more and more of it is pointing to closures(blocks).  Closures are very nice, but I feel like they can take away from readability sometimes, or maybe i'm too old and just like my delegates ¯\_(ツ)_/¯...i'm only 27 though lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no further parameters.

The closure is a replacement for `target` and `action` and `userInfo` is not needed either because the closure can capture values in the method before the call.

Here is an example:

```
var myTimer : Timer?

---

var counter = 0  
myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in 
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
    if counter == 10 { 
       timer.invalidate() 
       myTimer = nil
       print("timer stopped")
    }          
}
```